# How do I add a slide-in effect and a glowing effect using HTML5/CSS3 or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I think a description of what I am looking for will be best:

Let's say I have a sentence:  Hello World! This is KPO!

I want each word to show up 2 seconds after the latter has been displayed.  And I want KPO to be either a blinking or a fade in and fade out effect.

I am not sure where to start or what to use to accomplish this?

I was able to find a neon effect using CSS3 but it's not fading in and out so not sure.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: show us what you got so far and we will help you fix it

Comment: @ibu Sorry but all i have is the text and no effects yet.  that's why i didn't post anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can I would suggest using jQuery. There are a million plugins already made to do just this kind of text animation.

Comment: Thanks.  Any specific plugins you would like to recommend?

Comment: you can start here:http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/03/jquery-text-effects.html

Comment: Lol.  I was just on that page.  And thanks.  I might be able to use some of them.

Comment: gotta love google. This is not so hard to do by yourself though. If you muck around through the stackoverflow questions there are a lot of examples of animating text without a plugin. So if you are feeling adventurous, try making something new before buying a plugin.